# Is optimization dangerous?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I've read somewhere in the comments section of one of the questions here in stack overflow that:

Always start coding unoptimized.
If it meets the requirements then it's good,
else code an optimized version.
Check if the optimized code meets the requirements, if it meets the requirement, keep it but also keep the unoptimized version or paste the unoptimized version as a comment.
if the optimized version doesn't meet the requirements, delete it and stick with the unoptimized.

^Is there a term for this kind of programming? Is this a good or bad programming practice

Is optimization dangerous? The only reason I can think of is that it can create unnecessary complexity which can lead to errors. Is there anything else?

Is there a general rule to be followed about when one should optimize or not?

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil, some claim. While I do believe that it's counterproductive to tweak every step of the way, blatantly ignoring performance I believe is also bad practice. You should write code with everything you care about in mind, including performance and security.

Comment: "some claim"? like who? Is there any published writings about these?

Comment: Optimize when you have working code, with a test suite, but the code is not fast enough for its intended purpose. At that point optimization can be fact-based, based on measurement not guesswork.

Comment: @rid but as Purrfection already suggested, keep the full quote in mind: We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.

Comment: That advice is like the advice to always drive too slowly on the highway, wait until someone bumps into you from behind, and then decide to speed up a little - repeat until you're no longer being hit from behind. You have the requirements - you can, at least to some extend, anticipate in advance whether something has to be fast.

Comment: @harold: It's called gradient ascent ;)

Comment: I think it's always good practice to first write code that handles needed things and is really clear to read. Then you can check if there is some parts that can be "optimized". And by optimizing i don't mean shortening code, but really optimizing for speed and memory usage etc.

Comment: This is both heavily opinion-based, and better suited to programmers stack exchange.

Comment: The reason premature optimization is bad is - people have been taught stupid concepts about *what it is*. Sure - big-O matters, and cache misses, but here's reality: programmers go nuts with big class structures when something simple would do the job. Then when it's slow, they talk about profiling and maybe even do it - and it doesn't help. If you *sample* the problem, you point out it's because it's too complicated. If you ask them why, they say that's what they were taught, and it's good big-O. So where is "premature optimization" in this whole picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimising code takes time from the developers that they could instead use to add new features or polish their product. Since the end goal of development is not the code but the product that is build with it, spending time on optimisation should be balanced with the other uses that could be done of that time.

It's a waste when the effort is spent on code that does not end up in the product due to a change in the requirements. If optimisation is performed from the beginning, you may also spend lots of time optimising a part of the code that only marginally contribute to the overall time spent by the application.

Instead, you should probably wait until you have a clear vision of what the application is and what are the bottleneck before spending too much effort on optimisation. And then, you'll have a large suite of unit tests and of use cases that will allow you to optimise in confidence that you don't break the application and only spend your effort on parts that are really worth optimising thanks to profiling.

As always in engineering, optimisation is a tradeoff that you make. And you should definitely be sure that it is going to payoff before doing it if you mind your resources (time, money, ...).

Answer (score 2):

If optimization (by your compiler) is breaking your code while you believe it should not,

- your code is not following the language standard, or
- your compiler is broken, and you should upgrade it.

Language standards are quite complex to understand (in particular because not everything is specified, and some things are explicitly left unspecified or implementation specific). Read about [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Compilers are in practice tested a big lot, and you should often first suspect your own code, and only after be sure your code is right (and fully standard conforming) suspect the compiler (in other words, compiler optimization bugs -where the generated code is *wrong*- are quite rare in practice).

<sup>Be sure to upgrade your compiler to a recent version. For GCC it is today (december 2013) 4.8.2; don't blame GCC if you are using a 4.4 or 3.6 GCC compiler, these ancient versions are not maintained anymore!</sup>

In practice, enable all warnings and debugging info when developping your code (e.g. compile with `gcc -Wall -g` at least, perhaps even with `-Wextra`). When you are sure of the quality of your code, compile it with optimizations and warnings (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g -O2`) and test it a lot.

In practice, *profile* the execution of your tests and (when possible) focus your efforts on the hot code (the one taking most of the CPU time).

Comment: .... but sometimes you don't have really a choice, see audio codec implementation on ARM devices, in that case you need to get benefit from DSP ARM assembly extensions that can only be mapped on C code with multiple line instructions (highly inefficient), compilers cannot do a good job there, and you must be diffident :)

Comment: @Jekyll: I agree with your comment, but I cannot understand the relation to my answer. Yes, sometimes using `asm` in non-portable C code is necessary!

Comment: I was sure I posted directly under the question... I wanted to add an answer on the root of evil :D... I'll remove this comment and I'll make an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In general, optimized code is more complex and difficult to get correct. It's also often counter productive to optimize code early (simply because you may be spending time optimizing something that doesn't provide any real improvement in overall performance).

So the guidance you're asking about really boils down to:

- write code that easier to write and verify that it's correct
- optimize that code when it makes sense to expend the effort

No matter how fast it runs, incorrect code is not optimized code.

Comment: Optimized code is usually also less modular/reusable, more likely to break, harder to debug, and more difficult to maintain for programmers who will inherit your code.

Answer (score 2):

Always profile before optimizing. If a small amount of code takes up a majority of the execution time and you can prove this from your profiling results, consider the programming effort to write, test, reprofile, maintain, and have someone else inherit this added complexity. Once you've done this, revert your code back to before you optimized it for runtime and deoptimized it for readability. Just don't do it. Seriously, unless over 90% of your execution is spent on one function, it's not worth the effort.

Keep in mind that a speedup of 10x on code that consumes 90% of your runtime will decrease your total runtime by a factor of ~5. A speedup of infinity on that slow function still only speeds up your entire program by a factor of 10. If you're hoping for more than an order of magnitude speed improvement (which is my threshold for whether I may start o think about optimizing), you will need to change how you approach a problem, and this kind of change means rethinking the architecture of the program. If you're lucky, it may be as simple as replacing your queue with a priority queue. Most likely you won't be lucky. Sorry the answer is bleak.

Answer (score 1):

Premature optimization is the root of all evil .... but sometimes you don't have really a choice, see audio codec implementation on ARM devices, in that case you need to get benefit from DSP ARM assembly extensions (like `QADD, QSUB, QDADD, and QDSUB`
) that can only be mapped on C code with multiple line instructions (highly inefficient), compilers cannot do a good job there, so you will need to optimize code inlining assembly.
You will probably write a "non optimized code" first in that case, but with the optimization in mind... so that when you will add optimization you won't need to change your code too much.

Another case in which you know you will need to optimize your code is when you will write signal processing functions (correlation, convolution, fft) for embedded devices. In that case you will have to do algorithmic optimization (choose the best method to approach the problem, choose the right approximation) and code optimizations (to use the pipeline properly for example) and it will be good to know that you are going to optimize the code before starting doing it (expecially the algorithmic one that can be performed on paper even before coding, and that can be tested separately).

Comment: Some compilers are able to *vectorize* i.e. to use *one* machine instructions to implement *several* operations in the *C* source code.

Comment: I have never seen a compiler able to implement something like a `QDADD` in one clock cycle up to now.

Comment: I don't know much about `QADD` or ARM but some recent patches on the GCC mailing lists seem to focus that particular point. So expect some progress in GCC 4.9

Comment: Let's see ... it will save a lot of time, up to know people have only two choises. 1) Create their c extensions. 2) Porting and hacking libraries like IPP on ARM devices. The second one is not really good, so everyone reinvents the wheel like here: https://code.google.com/p/g729/source/browse/trunk/basic_op.c

Comment: Ouch. I wouldn't wish dropping down to assembly level on my worst enemies. I'm thankful for the brave souls who can think at the hardware level.